# Laplacian of exponential of vector norm (for heat equation)

Tags: vectors, calculus

First I have $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}=D\nabla^2_{\vec{u}}V$$ i.e the 3D heat equation, and I want to verify a solution for V. However, the solution includes the term $e^{-|\vec{u}-\vec{u_0}|^2}$ and I'm not sure how this works in the Laplacian. To be clear $u_0$ is $u$ at $t = 0$. Does it just end up looking similar to 1D differentiation? Admittedly my vector calculus could use some brushing up, and I might just be confused by the norm or coordinates or something.

Comment: Just use that $|\vec{v}|=\sqrt{\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is
$$\tag{1}
   V(\vec{u};t) = N \exp{\frac{|\vec{u}-\vec{u}_0|^2}{4 D t}}
$$
Where $N$ is the normalization constant $N = \frac{1}{(6\pi D t)^{3/2}}$

To do the Laplacian of Eq.(1), you may decompose it in the cartesian coordinate. Assume $\vec{u} = (x, y, z)$, and $\vec{u}_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$

\begin{multline} \tag{2}
  \nabla^2 V(\vec{u};t) =\left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right) N \exp{\frac{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}{4 D t}}
\end{multline}

Do the derivative of each component separatiedly,
\begin{multline} 
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} N \exp{\frac{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}{4 D t}} \\
=\frac{N}{2Dt} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left\{(x-x_0) \exp{\frac{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}{4 D t}} \right\}\\
=\frac{N}{2Dt} \exp{\frac{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}{4 D t}} \\
+ \frac{N}{(2Dt)^2} (x-x_0)^2 \exp{\frac{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}{4 D t}}
\end{multline}

Similar for the components $y$ and $z$. The Eq. (2) becomes:
\begin{multline} 
 D \nabla^2 V(\vec{u};t) =D\left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right) N \exp{\frac{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}{4 D t}} \\
=3D\frac{N}{2Dt} \exp{\frac{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}{4 D t}}\\
+D\frac{N}{(2Dt)^2} \left[ (x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2 \right] \exp{\frac{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}{4 D t}}\\
=\frac{3N}{2t} \exp{\frac{|\vec{u}-\vec{u}_0|^2}{4 D t}} + \frac{N}{4Dt^2}  |\vec{u}-\vec{u}_0|^2 \exp{\frac{|\vec{u}-\vec{u}_0|^2}{4 D t}}\\
=\frac{3}{2t} V(\vec{u};t) + \frac{|\vec{u}-\vec{u}_0|^2}{4Dt^2}   V(\vec{u};t).
\end{multline}

These two terms will cancle the two terms from the time derivative.